# Should I tell my current employer about a job I have lined up after my current contract ends?

Tags: professionalism, job-change, contracts

My current contract is coming to an end fairly soon and my bosses informed me a few months ago that my contract would not be renewed.

Interestingly, I had to directly ask my boss whether this was the case, as they were preparing to tell me a number of months further down the line. Thankfully, I asked in advance and was able to apply for a new position, which I recently interviewed for and was awarded the job.

In terms of job etiquette, should I inform my current boss that I have a job lined up after this one ends? I suppose that given that they haven't offered to extend my contract that they probably will not care either way, however, this is the first time I've been in this situation and I'd like to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

It's none of their concern as they will no longer be your employer. The only reason to mention it would be for reference purposes but as you've already signed the new contract, you probably don't need to do that here either.

Answer (score 3):

There is no strict etiquette in this situation. Had the situation been a bit different and they were discussing the renewal terms of your contract with you staying on in mind, it should be mentioned in either a contract negotiating way or as a legitimate reason to not continue working there.

However, from what you said they have no intention of keeping you on so in terms of transparency you don't really owe them anything other than a polite 'goodbye/good luck' as you walk out of the door for the last time. The only time I would consider telling them is if it came up organically in conversation i.e. I was asked what my plans for the future were over coffee or lunch with my boss and/or peers.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I concur and I will probably abstain from telling them until they bring it up in conversation.

Comment: @LeifErikson No problem! Good luck on your next role

Answer (score 2):

> In terms of job etiquette, should I inform my current boss that I have
>   a job lined up after this one ends?

There's no need for you to inform your current boss what you will be doing once your employment there ends.

You may be asked about it, but you can be vague if you choose. That wouldn't be discourteous.

Either way, on your last day you should thank them and perhaps say that you enjoyed working with them and would look forward to doing it again at some point in the future. That ensures that you won't be burning any bridges.